# onsen ui で背景画像を設定したい

Tags: onsen-ui

Onsen UI を利用すると、style.css に body 設定で background を指定しても反映されません。
背景画像を設定したいのですが、どこかに良いサンプルはないでしょうか？

Comment: htmlを提示していただくと回答がつきやすいかもしれません。

Answer (score -1):

onsen-css-components.cssあたりに、「.page__background」というクラスがありますので、このクラスに定義してやれば反映すると思います。

```
.page__background {
  background-image:url('画像パス');
}
```